# how to echo a mysql datediff

Tags: php, mysql

i am just needing a little guidance on the following script, i have tried to echo out the results of a query but nothing seems to be output. Any help would be greatly appreciated.]]

```
  <?php 



// connect to the database_ 
$connection = mysqli_connect('****','root','****','****'); 
$guid=$_SESSION['guid'];         
$sam=$_GET['guid']; 
//prepare query to select all 
$query="SELECT datediff(MAX(date_of_incident),MIN(date_of_incident) AS        date_difference FROM incident)"; 


//run query and store results 
$results=mysqli_query($connection,$query); 



While($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){ 


echo $row['date_difference'];



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you errorcheck your result?

```
$results=mysqli_query($connection,$query); 
if ($results === false){
   echo "I have an error!";
} else {
   // inspect your resultset
}
```

In case of an error, I always run the offendig SQL directly against the database. Just echo your query, and copy past it into a commanline interface to your database (or phpmyadmin, or whatever you prefer).

Answer (score -1):

Close `)` this before `AS`

```
SELECT datediff(MAX(date_of_incident),MIN(date_of_incident)) AS 
                                                           ^^
date_difference FROM incident
                            ^^
```

Try this code :-

```
$query="SELECT 
datediff(MAX(date_of_incident),MIN(date_of_incident))
AS date_difference  
FROM incident";
```

Comment: if my answer helps you please accept my answer @tait1